# Does filtering in lightning-record-picker support SOSL?

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, lookup, sosl

I am using the [lightning-record-picker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-picker/documentation) component and I am querying an object which has its 'Name' field encrypted. This means that I'm returning a '*the like operator is not supported on an encrypted field*' in the browser console.

Neither the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-graphql.html docs nor the lightning-record-picker docs explictly say that filtering doesn't work with SOSL but it seems like it is implied.

Does filtering in lightning-record-picker support SOSL? If not, presumably I shall have to adopt a custom lookup version in LWC as per https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc.

Comment: I can see nothing that allows to select use of SOSL for any of the matching with this component. I suspect you will need to use a custom component.